# JavaFx Detect Forward/Back Button on MouseEvent

Tags: java, javafx

I've been reading for about an hour or so in the JavaFx API's to see if there is a way I can check if the forward/back button on some mice have been pressed. Is this even supported in JavaFx?

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry accidentally added that tag.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it from the documentation, but the best way to check, if you have such a mouse, is to see it it indeed raises a `MouseEvent`, and if so what value you get in `getButton`

Comment: @sillyfly tried this but no event gets fired when pressing the forward/back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this is impossible at the moment, but there is an RFE: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090930, so it may be possible in future Java versions.

Comment: I have opened a pull request on OpenJFX's Github that adds support for the forward and back mouse buttons: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/pull/173. When it's merged, and a new release of JavaFX is made, this functionality will be available.